# How do I get sub millisecond latency between two Azure VMs (ARM) on same (Regional) VNET?

Tags: azure

I can get sub millisecond latency between two Standard_D2_V2 West Europe Classic (ASM) VMs in the same Cloud Service with the cloud service assigned to an affinity group.

I can also get sub millisecond latency between the VMs in an Azure VM Scale Set.

But I cannot seem to get sub millisecond latency between two Azure ARM VMs (sharing the same (Regional) VNET). Is there a way to reliably get sub millisecond latency between ARM VMs without deploying as a Scale Set like you could with affinity groups in Azure classic/ASM?

Below are my measurements for the various scenarios. I have deployed the various scenarios multiple times to rule out, as best I can, lucky vs. unlucky deployments.

**Two ASM(classic) VMs in same cloud service assigned to an affinity group (not connected via VNET!!)**

```
PS C:\Users\simon> .\psping -l 1k -n 10000 -h 13.81.205.180:60123

PsPing v2.10 - PsPing - ping, latency, bandwidth measurement utility
Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

TCP latency test connecting to 13.81.205.180:60123: Connected
10005 iterations (warmup 5) sending 1024 bytes TCP latency test: 100%

TCP roundtrip latency statistics (post warmup):
  Sent = 10000, Size = 1024, Total Bytes: 10240000,
  Minimum = 0.11ms, Maxiumum = 6.23ms, Average = 0.45ms

Latency Count
0.11    6042
0.43    2721
0.75    846
```

**Azure ARM VM Scale Set VMs**

```
PS C:\Users\simon> .\psping -l 1k -n 20000 -h 10.0.0.7:60123

TCP roundtrip latency statistics (post warmup):
  Sent = 20000, Size = 1024, Total Bytes: 20480000,
  Minimum = 0.18ms, Maxiumum = 9.62ms, Average = 0.48ms

Latency Count
0.18    19733
0.68    178
```

**Azure ARM VM to Azure ARM VM on same (regional) vnet**

```
PS C:\Users\simon> .\psping -l 1k -n 20000 -h 10.0.0.7:60123

TCP roundtrip latency statistics (post warmup):
  Sent = 20000, Size = 1024, Total Bytes: 20480000,
  Minimum = 1.59ms, Maxiumum = 10.60ms, Average = 1.81ms

Latency Count
1.59    19401
2.07    379
2.54    98
```

Comment: have you considered network intensive vms with RDMA? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-a8-a9-a10-a11-specs#access-to-the-rdma-network, also, what's wrong with Scale Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor Pagliai (@igorpag) kindly gave me the following suggestions on twitter:

"If not possible to use VM with RDMA, you can try with VM in same Availability Set. Something new will come soon in Azure." and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-accelerated-networking-portal

I went with his Availability Set suggestions, and created an availability set with a single fault domain, the portal gave the following tooltip for fault domain "Virtual machines in the same fault domain share a common ... physical network switch.", which sounded very promising, and the results did not disappoint:

**Azure ARM VMs same availability set/fault domain (sub millisecond latency, yippee!)**

```
PS C:\Users\simon> .\psping -l 1k -n 10000 -h 10.0.0.4:60123

TCP roundtrip latency statistics (post warmup):
  Sent = 10000, Size = 1024, Total Bytes: 10240000,
  Minimum = 0.13ms, Maxiumum = 7.93ms, Average = 0.22ms

Latency Count
0.13    9742
0.54    194
0.95    55
```